# How to modify numeric element in an array in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Sorry for my lake of understanding. I stored 5 elements in an array and I can easily add, insert, remove elements to this array but I am not able to modify a specific element.

I have an array

```
"Queue" : [ 1,2,3,4,5,3,3,3,3,3,8,9 ]
```

I want to replace all 3 with 25 . Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doing a [partial update](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/partial-document-updates) on an array doesn't seem to be possible. I suspect your option would be to do this on the client, or restructure your data.

Answer (score 1):

Load the document, do this on the client, save the doc.